# How to go through an array apply a threshold to each pixel

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy

I have a 3 channel numpy array and I would like to apply a function to each pixel. Specifically I want to process an image and return a greyscale image highlighting where specific colours appear in the image. If the red, green, blue channels are within 10 in L2 distance from the colour: (30,70,130) then set that pixel's value on the greyscale image to be 255, otherwise 0.

My current process to doing it is with:

```
def L2_dist(p1,p2):
    dist = ( (p1[0]-p2[0] )**2 + (p1[1]-p2[1] )**2 + (p1[2]-p2[2] )**2 ) **0.5
    if dist<10: return 255
    return 0

def colour_img(image):
    colour = my_colour
    img_dim = image.shape
    new_img = np.zeros((img_dim[0],img_dim[1])) # no alpha channel replica
    for c in range(img_dim[0]):
        for r in range(img_dim[1]):
            pixel = image[r,c,:3]
            new_img[r,c] = L2_dist(colour,pixel)
    return new_img
```

But it's very slow. How can I do this faster instead of using loops?

Answer (score 2):

## Simple one line solution

You can do what you want in a single line like this:

```
new_img = (((image - color)**2).sum(axis=2)**.5 <= 10) * 255
```

## Optimized two line solution

The above line isn't the most efficient way possible to perform all of the operations that the OP wants. Here's a significantly faster way (credit to Paul Panzer for suggesting the optimizations in the comments, readability not guaranteed):

```
d = image - color
new_img = (np.einsum('...i, ...i', d, d) <= 100) * 255
```

## Timings:

Given some test data with 100x100 pixels:

```
import numpy as np

color = np.array([30, 70, 130])
# random data within [20,60,120]-[40,80,140] for demo purposes
image = np.random.randint(10*2 + 1, size=[100,100,3]) + color - 10
```

Here's a comparison of the timings of the OP's method and the solutions from this answer. The one-line solution is about 100x faster than than the OP's, whereas the fully optimized version is about 300x faster:

```
%%timeit
# OP's code
img_dim = image.shape
new_img = np.zeros((img_dim[0],img_dim[1])) # no alpha channel replica
for c in range(img_dim[0]):
    for r in range(img_dim[1]):
        pixel = image[r,c,:3]
        new_img[r,c] = L2_dist(color,pixel)

43.8 ms ± 502 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
# one line solution
new_img = (((image - color)**2).sum(axis=2)**.5 <= 10) * 255

439 µs ± 13.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
# fully optimized solution
d = image - color
new_img = (np.einsum('...i, ...i', d, d) <= 100) * 255

145 µs ± 2.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

#### Explanation of simple one line solution

The simple one-liner given as the first solution will:

- Find the Euclidean distance between every pixel in `image` (which will be an array of shape `(m, n, 3)`) and `color` (which will be an array of shape `(3)`).
- Check if any of those distances is within `10`, and return a boolean array that is `True` wherever the condition is met and `False` otherwise.
- A boolean array is really just an array of `0`s and `1`s, so we then multiply the boolean array by `255` to get the final result you wanted.

#### Explanation of optimized solution

Here's the list of optimizations used:

- Uses `einsum` to calculate the sum of the squares required for the distance calculation. Under the hood, `einsum` makes use of the BLAS library that Numpy wraps to calculate the needed sum-product, so it should be faster.
- Skips taking the square root by comparing the square of the distance to the square of the threshold.
- I tried to find a way to minimize allocation/copying of arrays, but this actually made things slower. Here's a version of the optimized solution that allocates exactly two arrays (one for intermediate results and one for final result) and makes no other copies:

  ```
  %%timeit
  # fully optimized solution, makes as few array copies as possible
  scr = image.astype(np.double)
  new_img = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
  np.multiply(np.less_equal(np.einsum('...i,...i', np.subtract(image, color, out=scr), scr, out=scr[:,:,0]), 100, out=new_img), 255, out=new_img)

  232 µs ± 7.72 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
  ```

Comment: You can avoid the square root by comparing to 100 instead of 10.

Comment: Oooo, nice one. I'll add that. I was busy trying to figure out how to do it with as few array allocations/copies as possible. There's no way to cast directly from `bool` to `int` without a copy, right?

Comment: You could viewcast to int8 or uint8 but in this case it is not necessary because multiplying by 255 will coerce anyway.

Comment: True, so the `astype(int)` in my answer wasn't necessary. But if `new_img` is of dtype `bool` (as per the result of the comparison op), both `new_img *= 255` and `new_img = new_img.view(dtype=np.int)` fail (with `TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc multiply output...` and `ValueError: When changing to a larger dtype...`). So I can't get around making a copy that way...

Comment: Also, if you want it really fast, do not compute the scalar product manually. Use one of the blas dependent methods  instead: `einsum('...i,...i), d, d)` or `(d[..., None, :]@d[..., None])[..., 0, 0]`. (`d = image-color`)

Comment: What you can do is `new_img = new_img.view(np.uint8)` `new_img *= 255`.

Comment: That or write your own. Seriously though, thank you for the back and forth. That was educational. I still have a zillion questions, but those will wait for another thread.

Comment: @tel, include the numba solution in your answer as well and then I'll delete my answer. Your's is pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
color = np.array([30, 70, 130])
L2 = np.sqrt(np.sum((image - color) ** 2, axis=2))  # L2 distance of each pixel from color

img_dim = image.shape
new_img = np.zeros((img_dim[0], img_dim[1]))
new_img[L2 < 10] = 255
```

But as you can see, we are iterating though the array twice, first to calculate `L2` and then to do the thresholding in `L2 < 10`, We can improve it as is done in your code, through nested loops. But, loops in python are slow. So, JIT compile the function to get the fastest version. Below I use numba:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(cache=True)
def L2_dist(p1,p2):
    dist = (p1[0]-p2[0] )**2 + (p1[1]-p2[1] )**2 + (p1[2]-p2[2] )**2
    if dist < 100: return 255
    return 0

@nb.njit(cache=True)
def color_img(image):
    n_rows, n_cols, _ = image.shape
    new_img = np.zeros((n_rows, n_cols), dtype=np.int32)
    for c in range(n_rows):
        for r in range(n_cols):
            pixel = image[r, c, :3]
            new_img[r,c] = L2_dist(color,pixel)
    return new_img
```

**Timings**:

```
# @tel's fully optimised solution(using einsum to short circuit np to get to BLAS directly, the no sqrt trick)
128 µs ± 6.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

# JITed version without the sqrt trick
30.8 µs ± 10.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# JITed version with the sqrt trick
24.8 µs ± 11.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

HTH.